# The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/NAME.pid)

Tags: macos, homebrew, mysql

I have installed mysql via brew. First start works, but after reboot, I got the following error:

```
The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/NAME.pid)
```

I start mysql with

```
sudo mysql.server restart
```

If I try to create a pid file on my own via terminal it will created, but after a few seconds it disappear.

```
sudo touch /usr/local/var/mysql/NAME.pid
```

Have anyone a idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67915826/6341943 check this out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YES.

Following homebrew caveats, did you setup launchd?

```
To have launchd start mysql at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load mysql now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Well, now using **`mysql.server`** is pointless. It basically doesn't work, because (from my poor understanding) **mysqld** is now managed by **launchd**, and it is `mysqld_safe`. I don't know if actually because of that is different from what you control with `mysql.server`.

The solution I came up with is to **not use** launchd for mysql from brew.
Rather, I just use the  `mysql.server` tool to start, stop, and restart mysql.

If you want to follow my steps, this is what you need to do:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

And whenever you want to start the mysql server, use `mysql.server start`.

If you actually want to make mysql start at boot time, you can take that plist and copy it, delete the KeepAlice line, replace the string values under `ProgramArguments` with `/usr/local/bin/mysql.server` and `start`. After that do
`launchctl load ~/path/to/com.file.plist`

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't use `mysql.server` anymore, instead I use `brew services` which in turn managed `launchd`.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

> sudo mysqld_safe &

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/mysql/` , I've had installed from brew.

Comment: thanks worked for me. I am wondering why this permission was not there to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

just run `mysqld` (don't run as root) from your terminal, you're mysql server will restarts and resets everything like show in the picture:

[image]

and use:

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue and by following these steps solved it successfully.

Find the file `/usr/local/var/mysql/your_computer_name.local.err` to understand more about the error.

It's probably a problem with permissions:

1. Find if mysql is running and kill it

   ```
   ps -ef | grep mysql
   kill -9 PID
   ```

   where PID is second column value
2. Check ownership of mysql

   ```
   ls -laF /usr/local/var/mysql/
   ```
3. If it is owned by root, change it to mysql or your user name

   ```
   sudo chown -R mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/
   ```

Answer (score -1):

sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/mysql/
worked for me as file permission was not there

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why, but deleting a file called something like `/usr/local/var/mysql/Andrejs-MacBook-Pro.local.err` and running `mysql.server start` worked for me.

As detailed [here](http://blog.antas.cz/error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file).

Answer (score -1):

This is what I had to do (installed from brew):

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/var/mysql/
```

Answer (score -1):

For conventional installations, without brew, like mine, the solutions above doesn't worked. The solution came with the permission repair, using the Utilities Disk App from OS X. Just run the app on your disk, restart, and try again. Only solution that worked here.